# not all code paths return a value? help needed

Tags: c#, console

I am making a c# console board game and I am having trouble trying to sort out this error that is currently linked to the static int ResetGame() part. Apparently not all code paths return a value. How do I fix this?

```
static int ResetGame()

{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tactical Space Cheese Racer");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of players that wish to play (2-4) : ");
    int NoOfPlayers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("");

    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the player: " + i + i++);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        players[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
        players[i].Pos = 0;
    }
}
```

I have more code available if you need to see it to resolve the problem

Comment: Your method claims to return an int, but you don't return one anywhere.

Comment: I would also change `Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the player: " + i + i++);` to `Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of player " + (i + 1).ToString() + ": ");`.  You shouldn't be incrementing the `i` variable there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that your method should return an `int` and you don't return it.

If you don't want to return anything, then you should state that your method is a `void` method.

```
static void ResetGame()  
{

}
```

As I can conclude from your code, this might was your intention. So making your method a `void` one, you will not have any problem.

Furthermore, I have to make a side note about the way you set the number of players. If the user enters a non integere value you will get an exception, that you don't handle. In addition to this, if the user enters an integer greater than 4, that shouldn't be ok. That being said you should take care both of the above.

```
int numberOfPlayers = -1;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of players that wish to play (2-4) : ");

// The method Int32.TryParse parses the input and check if it 
// can be represented as a 32-bit integer number.
// If parse succeeds, then the value is assigned to numberOfPlayers 
// and the method returns true. Otherwise, it returns false.
while(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()), out numberOfPlayers) && 
      !(numberOfPlayers>2 && numberOfPlayers<4))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number between (2-4): ");
}
```

**update**

Idle_Mind pointed out in his comment the following:

> I would say he needs to Return the Number of Players.

If that's the case, you just simple have to add this before the closing curly brace of your method:

```
return numberOfPlayers;
```

I suppose that you will keep my naming. If you will keep yours just change the name of the variable to yours.

Comment: I would say he needs to **Return the Number of Players**.  How else will he know which slots in the `players[]` structure are to be used?  What if in the last game, 4 people played, but in the new game only 2 people played?  The structure would have names and positions in the third and fourth slots, but only the first two slots should be used for the game...

Comment: @Idle_Mind ok, if Kieren Wells needs this, I think that is straightforward from the above how that can be done. I will update my post however in order this be stated explicitly.